# Making a linked list from a premade file

Tags: c++, oop, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to make a linked list from a premade file in c++. I'm struggling with the concept of taking the info if get from the file and using that to make the list.  this is what i have so far.I also need to have the ability to insert and delete node from anywhere in the list.

```
struct node
{
    string name;
    int id;
    float gpa;
    node *next;
};
struct node* head;
void insertNodes(short id)
{
    struct node* new_node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->id = id;
    new_node->next = head;
    head = new_node;
}
void deleteNode() {
    if (head == NULL){
        cout << "List is empty" << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << head->id << " is removed." << endl;
    head = head ->next;
}
int main() {
    head = NULL;
    node entry;
    fstream datafile;

    datafile.open("datafile.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (!datafile)
    {
        cout << "Error!!\n";
        return 0;
    }
    datafile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&entry), sizeof(entry)); 
}
```

Comment: You need to identify and describe a specific issue, then ask a question.  Here you have shown a program that reads binary data from a file.  How did you build this file?  What problems are you having?  What behavior do you expect?  Please edit your question and add relevant detail.

Comment: Is this a school or university project? If not, don't try to build your own linked list, there's already one in standard library (`std::list`, doubly linked; `std::forward_list`, singly linked).

Comment: @Aconcagua given his description and if it is a school project: its likely they are learning to implement list or singly-linked list

Comment: Prefer to use `operator new` rather than `malloc`.  The `malloc` does not initialize memory nor does it call the constructor of the `struct` or `class`.

Comment: `malloc` and `free` (I don't see any reference to the latter -> memory leak!) is not what one should use in C++, `new` and `delete` is what you'd rather use here...

Comment: `datafile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&entry), sizeof(entry));` – there's a pointer in the node, you cannot expect that you can re-read the pointer you once wrote to file; probability that the object you linked to before is placed at the same location again is practically 0... You should first read about *serialisation* before you are going on with reading from/writing to file.

Answer (score 1):

if you are doing this in C++ you shouldn't be using `malloc` and `free` generally, and the `struct` keyword before every instance of the struc; those are C-ism's.  You should probably be creating a class of your own to represent the list and using member functions instead of a global variables `head`, and using `new` and `delete` for dynamic instantiation and destruction of variables.  There are cases for malloc still but this does not appear to be one them.

additionally your insert function only seems to take an input value and add it to the tail of the list; generally in a list you will want to take the insertion point and value unless you are calling the method 'pushback' or something along those lines.

Further unless you rewrite to make a `List` class of your own you have not done any object oriented programming currently, as you are just doing things procedurally and the only thing c++ about this code is the use of `iostream` and `fstream`.

Suggest that you make node a class as well. it's mostly semantic but will get you in the habit, and give node a constructor even if you don't want to make accessors.

beyond that you are asking for information without having attempted anything and your question is too broad.